# Let title distinct in mainmatter and TOC and header

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, header-footer

Title in mainmatter (long title):

---

**Sec.1  The introduction of TEX --- A powerful typsetting system**

blabla...

**Sec.2  installation**

blabla...

---

Title in TOC (short title, line break before em dsah):

---

```
Sec.1  TEX
       --- A typsetting system ....................... 1

Sec.2  Installation .................................. 2
```

---

Title in header (short title):

---

*Sec.1 TEX --- A typesetting system*

---

Comment: It depends on the class you are using. For example, memoir provides two optional arguments to `\section` just to distinguish among the actual title, the short title for the toc and the short title for the header.

Answer (score 5):

In the `article` document class you can use the optional argument of `\section` to change the entry in the ToC; this change will also affect the header, but using `\markright` you can control header; the following example illustrates this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[\TeX\\--- A typsetting system]{The introduction of \TeX ---A powerful typsetting system}
\markright{Section \thesection. \TeX ---A typsetting system}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

The `memoir` document class offers two optional arguments for the `\section` command; the first one will control the ToC entry, and the second one will control the header; a little example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[\TeX\\--- A typsetting system][\TeX ---A typsetting system]{The introduction of \TeX ---A powerful typsetting system}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @dearmath: Since my answer seems to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count.